# Free Positioning of Object and Line Between Them

Tags: swiftui

I'm working on an ERD app and I'm having trouble understanding what approach Apple intended for these use cases where a precise calculated position of subviews has to be established.

The code is working with two types of custom views: `EntityView` and `RelationView`.

`EntityView` is a view depicting an entity with multiple hard-coded attributes whereas `RelationView` is a dynamically-generated `Path` between two `CGPoints`.

On my `ContentView` I try to create two instances of an `EntityView` and display a `RelationView` between them but struggle to understand what logic I should use for positioning.

**ContentView**

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var entities = [EntityView(), EntityView()]
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            ZStack {
                entities[0]
                    .position(x: entities[0].width, y: entities[0].height)
                
                entities[1]
                    .position(x: 600, y: 700)
                
                RelationView(startPoint: CGPoint(x: entities[0].width, y: entities[0].height), endPoint: CGPoint(x: 600, y: 700))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**EntityView**

```
struct EntityView: View, Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let blueColor = Color(red: 0/255, green: 48/255, blue: 87/255)
    let entityTitle = "Customer"
    let attributes = ["Attribute 1", "Attribute 2", "Attribute 3"]
    let width:Double
    let height:Double
    
    init() {
        let widestString = getWidthOfWidestString(stringArray: attributes + [entityTitle])
        self.width = max(widestString, 200)
        self.height = Double(40 + attributes.count * 30 + 6)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 6)
                .frame(width: (width) + 2, height: CGFloat(self.height))
                .foregroundColor(blueColor)
            
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
                .frame(width: width, height: CGFloat(40 + attributes.count * 30))
                .foregroundColor(.white)
            
            VStack(spacing: 0) {
                // MARK: Entity
                ZStack {
                    Rectangle()
                        .fill(blueColor)
                    Text(entityTitle)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                }
                .frame(height: 40)
                
                // MARK: Attributes
                ForEach(attributes, id:\.self) { attribute in
                    ZStack {
                        Rectangle()
                            .foregroundColor(Color(uiColor: .lightGray))
                        Text(attribute)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                    }
                    .frame(height: 30)
                }
                .padding(.top, 1)
            }
            .frame(width: width)
            .cornerRadius(5)
        }
    }
}
```

**RelationView**

```
struct RelationView: View {
    let startPoint:CGPoint
    let endPoint:CGPoint
    
    var body: some View {
        let minSize = getMinSize(startPoint: startPoint, endPoint: endPoint)
        let relativeStartPoint = CGPoint(x: startPoint.x - minSize.width, y: startPoint.y - minSize.height)
        let relativeEndPoint = CGPoint(x: endPoint.x - minSize.width, y: endPoint.y - minSize.height)
        
        Path({ path in
            path.addLines([
                relativeStartPoint,
                CGPoint(x: (relativeStartPoint.x + relativeEndPoint.x) / 2, y: relativeStartPoint.y),
                CGPoint(x: (relativeStartPoint.x + relativeEndPoint.x) / 2, y: relativeEndPoint.y),
                relativeEndPoint
            ])
        })
            .stroke()
            .frame(width: abs(endPoint.x - startPoint.x), height: abs(endPoint.y - startPoint.y))
    }
}

func getMinSize(startPoint:CGPoint, endPoint:CGPoint) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: min(startPoint.x, endPoint.x), height: min(startPoint.y, endPoint.y))
}
```

Result:
[image: iPad Preview]

Comment: I can store the view inside the model but it won't change anything about how the app is displayed.

Also, which hardcodes are you referring to? I'm still in the mock up phase so ContentView is very much hardcoded just to ensure I can get the proper positioning with anticipated values. I can deal with making it dynamic once I know I can get static values to work

Comment: Yes. I only hardcoded the value 600 because I knew it would show on the preview. Obviously I'd make this dynamic long before it goes into production. I'm struggling to get the line position right even with hard-coded predictable position of the entities which is a pre-requisite to getting it work with dynamic position of entities

Comment: I'm trying to create an ERD app. If you look up entity relation diagrams you'll see what is it I'm trying to achieve